# How to insert large amount of numbers inside a number efficiently?

Tags: python

Say I have a number x such that x.length = 500. Say in position 5 and 8, from the left, I want to insert a number. But I want to insert a number such that it goes through all digits. So in essence it goes through all 10^2 possibilities.

I then want to go through all possibilities and do an "if statement" to return the correct one.

I thought about changing it to a string, inserting it where I want then changing it back to a number. But I think this might be inefficient. And then if I want to check all the numbers, it is further inefficient.

I care so much about efficiency because my aim is to insert more than 2 numbers. I am wanting like 7 or 8, in position 125, 315, so on. This is large (10^8). Once again I want to check all these numbers too.

I have not made code yet because I do not know how to do this properly.

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Convert you 500 digit number to a string, then a list, then back to a number

```
# Here's an example of a long number
big_number = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

# Make it a string
big_number_string = str(big_number)

# Add each char to a list
big_num_list = [y for y in big_number_string]
# ['1','1','1','1','1',...]

# Insert '0' at index 10
big_num_list.insert(10, '0')
# [...'1','1','1','0','1',...]

# Join everything together and make it a number again
big_num_new = int(''.join(big_num_list))

print(big_num_new)
>> 11111111110111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: `[y for y in big_number_string]` can be written as `list(big_number_string)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def gen_candidates(number, indices):
    # inserting at an index will make all larger indices off by one
    powers_of_ten = [10 ** (i + index) for i, index in enumerate(sorted(indices))]

    for power in powers_of_ten:
        everything_less = number % power
        number = ((number - everything_less) * 10) + everything_less

    for value_at_digit in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=len(indices)):
        yield number + sum(
            value * power for value, power in zip(value_at_digit, powers_of_ten)
        )


result = list(gen_candidates(11111111111111111111111111111, [0, 0, 22, 14, 6, 7, 7, 8]))
print(len(result), result[0], result[-1])
# 100000000 1111111011111111011111101001011111100 1111111911111111911111191991911111199
```

you can then use this generator like this

```
# will try 12304050, 12304051, 12304052 etc.
for number in gen_candidates(12345, [0, 1, 2]):
    if is_the_right_one(number):
        do_whatever(number)
```

With 8 indices it takes like 2 minutes on my desktop. The `for` loop adds the same number over and over while the other digits are changing, so you could improve the performance a bit. Or rewrite the code in a faster language.

Comment: I try with large number (500 digits long) with 2 indices and it takes a long time. I think the larger the number the longer it will take.

Comment: @yarl for me `list(gen_candidates(random.randrange(1, 10**500), [64, 424]))` is almost instant.

Comment: The number of indices is what dominates the run time, the length of the number has to change much more to have the same effect as adding one more index. In fact putting `10**50000` in the `randrange` takes a few seconds for me with 2 indices.

Comment: I'm guessing it's your comparison function that is taking the most time. Can you include it in your question?

Comment: can you try adding more indices and see how much time that takes?

Comment: I can already tell you that adding another index will make it take (almost) exactly 10 times longer.